# Edit XML file using XSD schema class generated in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

1. I have XML file
2. I have created the XSD for the xml file using Visual studio
3. Generated the C# class from XSD file
4. Referred the class in Project.

I want to edit the XML file to update innertext of few Nodes and save it.
Could you please let me know how to edit xml file using the XSD class generated.

Comment: If you want to edit xml you need to de-serialize the xml to put into classes.  Then modify class data.  The serialize the updated xml back to a file.

Comment: When we serialise the object it will save only the class object with data(Remaing nodes are lost)..all the other node values are not saved..how to edit the required nodes keeping the existing values as it is.Using XMLDocument we can load the xml,Select the node,Change the value and save it.But using serializer how to achieve the same

Comment: You have to use the same instance of the class that you used to de-serialize the data.  You are not using the same instance.